# Python working with objects

Tags: python, object

I have an object whose attributes need to be changed. It has just one attribute named length. There are values in a list named transformation which needs to be added to the length. Each needs to be added separately. So, for 4 values in the list, we will have 4 new "transformed" objects. For example,

```
transformation = [1 2 3 4]
objectSample = ClassSample()
for i in range(0,len(transformation)):
    newObject = ClassSample()
    newObject = TransformUsing(objectSample,transformation[i])
    storeInList(i,newObject)

def TransformUsing(self,obj,transformation):
    obj.length = obj.length + transformation
    return obj
```

However, when I iterate over the loop for the second time, the length addition becomes cumulative, meaning the effect of the first iteration stays. What is the way around?

Comment: You'll have to show us a minimal working example, as your question isn't clear and could be interpreted in about a dozen different ways.

Comment: Not enough information to answer, but note that since `transformation` is a list, you should do `for item in transformation: ... TransformUsing(item)` instead of indexing.  It is more Pythonic.

Comment: I modified the example to illustrate more.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reset length to 0 before the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your mistakes lies in this line:

```
newObject = TransformUsing(objectSample,transformation[i])
```

Which should be:

```
newObject = TransformUsing(newObject,transformation[i])
```

Other than the fact that your code initializes `newObject` with a new `ClassSample` and then doesn't use it, what happens is that with each iteration you are modifying *the same instance* of `ClassSample`, the one stored in `objectSample`, and then re-add it to the list. i.e., your entire list is comprised of references to the same object, and thus in each iteration you make a change to all the objects already in the list at once.